# pandas dataframe index column mapping TypeError: 'value' must be a scalar, passed: Series

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, indexing

I have a dataframe (Market and Ticker are indexes) and need to fill it with matching values

| Market | Ticker | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| APPLE | AAPL | 10 |
| FACEBOOK | META | 20 |

the dictionary looks like this:

```
{'OKTA': '53.72000', 'AAPL': '84.05000'}
```

As Market and Ticker are indexes are index, to add a column with "Close Price" works like this:
`df['Last Close'] = df.index.get_level_values('Ticker').map({'OKTA': '53.72000', 'AAPL': '84.05000'})`
This works!

| Market | Ticker | Quantity | Last Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APPLE | AAPL | 10 | 84.05000 |
| FACEBOOK | META | 20 |  |

However, when I tried to do another map with a new dictionary `new_dict = {'META': '53.72000', 'INSW': '84.05000'}`

```
df['Last Close'] = df.index.get_level_values('Ticker').map(new_dict).fillna(df['Last Close'])
```

```
<pre>
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-36-65a4b662d8c5> in <module>

      1 new_dict = {'META': '53.72000', 'INSW': '84.05000'}
----> 2 df['Last Close'] = df_op.index.get_level_values('Ticker').map(new_dict).fillna(df['Last Close'])
      3 df[['Quantity', 'Last Close']]

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in fillna(self, value, downcast)
   2804         """
   2805 
-> 2806         value = self._require_scalar(value)
   2807         if self.hasnans:
   2808             result = self.putmask(self._isnan, value)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _require_scalar(self, value)
   4950         """
   4951         if not is_scalar(value):
-> 4952             raise TypeError(f"'value' must be a scalar, passed: {type(value).__name__}")
   4953         return value
   4954 

TypeError: 'value' must be a scalar, passed: Series
</pre>
```

My current work around it to flatten the dataframe index by `df.index_reset(inplace=True)`. Once all mapped, then `df.set_index(["Market", "Ticker"])`

Comment: What do you expect by `.fillna(df['Last Close'])`? `df['Last Close']` is a `Series`, and it is expecting a numeric (scalar) value.

Comment: @AzharKhan, then why once I flatten the index, df['Last Close'] is still a Series, then
`df['Last Close'] = df['Ticker'].map(new_dict).fillna(df['Last Close'])` works?